# add model transformer to custom form type (only parent)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am building my special choice type.

```
class MyType extends AbstractType {

    public function getParent() { return ChoiceType::class; }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $this->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(); // <-- impossible
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setRequired('currentDataCategory');
        //....
    }
}
```

The thing is I dont want to add a FormField in  `buildForm`, because then I would have to know the name of the field. I just want to define my special ChoiceType.

**And I need to add a ModelTransformer**. If I did add a field, it would be easy:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('unkonwnname', ChoiceType::class);
    $builder->get('unkonwnname')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(); // <-- should work
}
```

So I think I am missing a general understanding of custom form types. All examples on the web show custom compound form types, where the name is known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addModelTransformer` is a method of the `FormBuilderInterface`. In your custom type, it should be called on the `$builder`, and not on `$this` (the custom type itself).

Comment: Thanks! Further question: If I wanted to set the choices dynamically, where could I do that?

Comment: There’s a couple ways to do it, but the easiest might be to define them in `configureOptions` either with an immediately available value, or via a options closure if you need access to the form options to determine the choices. `’choices’ => function(Options $options) {$choices = []; ... return $choices;}`

Comment: Ah, I was wondering when the parent's (ChoiceType) buildForm method was called. Maybe I can alter the `$options` argument... But the callback is a good Idea!